# How to make a slide in UIViewTableCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am trying to create a `UITableView` so that When the user touches my normal `UIViewTableCell` another `UIViewTableCell` slides in from the right side with a new cell format. This new `UIViewTableCell` does not leave the `UITableView`.

The `UIViewTableCell`s are 2 different custom Cells.

I was wondering if there is a way to swap one `UITableViewCell` that is of `X type` for another `UITableViewCell` that is of `Y type` with an animated sliding effect?

I've looked at the following code but I do not understand where do I place my Cell information.

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:myIndexPaths
                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewCellRowAnimationRight];
[tableView endUpdates];
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:myNewIndexPaths
                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewCellRowAnimationLeft];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Any guidance on how to do this is highly appreciate it.

PS: I am not looking for a repo. I would like to understand how this is done.

Comment: Unless I misunderstood the question, I would have all the data in one custom cell. That custom cell has a UIScrollView just large enough to carry the content of two cells. And then just put initialize it appropriately and have it scrolled in. That can be done even withtout the scroll view of course, but I think using a scroll view is much easier for you.

Comment: The alternative without: Put all your stuff in a container. Just a UIView. That serves as your content view. You could have one UIView subclass for each custom table view cell subclass that you currently have, but you would go on with only one custom talble view cell subclass that does not do mutch itself but carrying this very container (or subclasses of it respectively). Before you change the content, create a new container right off screen to the left. Then have both containers animated to the right by the width of the cell. After that release (nil) the old content container. Done.

Comment: @HermannKlecker I though about `UIScrollView` but I would prefer using `UITableViewCells` as they are easy to style and know for future projects

Comment: UITableViewCells as they are cannot do the trick. You could try creating a new UITableViewCell and then "transfer" the content view from the new cell to the old one and then release the new cell. After that do the animation get rid of the old content view. As you cannot easily re-link the new text view to the old cell etc (the related properties are readonly) you may have to move the labels and uiimage from the old content view to the new one and discard the subviews of the new content view after copying the data over. But that does not sound too easy as you are using custom cells anyway ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the way table view cell animation works is you update your data source (usually an array that you reference when providing cells to the table view), then call the animation methods. The table view calls `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` when you insert a cell, so it's important that they return the correct values.

In this situation, however, the number of cells remains the same so you can't use insertion and deletion. You can use cell reloading, however. Theoretically, every time `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is called you would add to a list of tapped index paths that should display the new kind of cell. Alternatively, if you only want one of these special cells present at a time, you would use a single `NSIndexPath` variable. Then you would call

```
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight]; //or left
```

Then, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you would check to see if the particular row requires a different type of cell, and you would return that new type there. That way, the code you need to present the new type of cell is insulated from the initializing of the new cell.

Hope this works for you!